# Trinity (Christians) = Trimurti (Hindus)?

Tags: trinity, comparative-religion, hinduism

I have heard about the concept ot Trimurti in Hinduism [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimurti). One for construction (Brahma), one for protection (Vishnu) and one for destruction (Shiva). And somehow I feel it is related to Trinity in Christianity. Are there any relations?

Comment: About the only similarity is the number three. The three persons of the Hindu Trimurti (त्रिमूर्तिः) did not share the same essence, unlike the three persons of the Christian Trinity who did share the same essence. This makes all the world of difference, for the Trimurti is hence polytheistic, while the Trinity remains monotheistic.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 I live in India, The hindus Do say that all the parts of the trimurti are nothing but the Brahma or the essence, Infact they believe all of them share the same essence "Brahma' they also believe in one God called the 'Brahma' the essence of all creation , hence there is no difference between the concept of trinity and trimurty except that the christian trinity has been obfuscated by contradictory descriptions.

Comment: @JesusBoughtIslam: Well, I'm sure they say that all people and things share of Brahma. That's pantheism. The Wiki article on Pantheism describes one Hindu belief from an Upanishad saying, "This whole universe is Brahman, from Brahman to a clod of earth." So you're comparing apples and oranges as Christianity considers pantheism to be heretical.

Comment: It is about Hinduism, not Christianity.

Comment: @AffableGeek We have the comparative religion tag and a good amount of questions with it. The *is* about Hinduism. It is *also* about Christianity. I say it's on topic.

Comment: Both of these beliefs had the same historical origin, and were just repackaged to sound good to the respective religious groups.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One could do a great deal worse than quote [another answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/15735/1377):

> There are several heresies that one needs to be careful of when discussing a topic such as this. For example, **Modalism** which declares that God is not three distinct persons, but that He merely reveals himself in three different forms. Or, **Arianism** which declares that Christ and the Holy Spirit are creations of the Father and not one in nature with Him. Or **Partialism** which declares that the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are not distinct persons of the Godhead, but are different parts of God each composing a third of the divine.

Each of the different views of the *Trimuti* within Hinduism falls into one or more of those camps. My analysis (based on Wikipedia) may not be complete, but I posit this:—

- Sauram: modalism
- Vishaivism: Arianism
- Shavism and Smartism: partialism

So: no, apart from both the Trinity and Trimurti being "three", there are no similarities. Specifically, the Trimurti denies that the three gods are wholly three and wholly one.

Answer (score 8):

**Trimurti and Trinity similarity:** The number "*Three*"

**Trimurti and Trinity differences:**

1. Trinity is Father, Son and Holy Spirit while Trimurti is Creator, Preserver and Destroyer.
2. Trinity is "Three persons in one God". Trimurti is "Three distinct gods"

   > *1 John 5:7 (NKJV)* For there are three that bear witness in heaven:
   >   the Father, the Word, and the Holy Spirit; and these three are one.
3. In the Trinity all three persons are participants in the creation while in Trimurti only Brahma is responsible for the creation.

   > *Genesis 1:2-3 (NKJV)* The earth was without
   >   form, and void; and darkness was on the face of the deep. And the
   >   ***Spirit of God*** was hovering over the face of the waters.
   >   Then ***God*** said, “Let there be light”; and there was light.
4. All the three persons in the Trinity always work together and are in agreement. In Trimurti Brahma the creator, Vishnu the preserver, and Shiva the destroyer all have different functions.

   > *John 5:30 (NKJV)* I can of Myself do nothing. As I hear, I judge; and
   >   My judgment is righteous, because I do not seek My own will but the
   >   will of the Father who sent Me.
5. Christianity is strictly a monotheistic religion but Hinduism is generally known as polytheistic.

   > *Deuteronomy 6:4 (NIV)*  Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one

Just as God is a Holy Trinity (Father, Son, Spirit), Satan also imitates God and creates the Unholy Trinity (Satan, Antichrist, False Prophet) at the end times (Revelation 12-13). An apologist Justin Martyr (100–165 AD) wrote that Satan always imitates God and His prophesies.

> When they [**wicked demons**] heard it predicted through the prophets that
>   Christ was to come, and that impious men would be punished by fire,
>   they put forward a number of so-called sons of Zeus, thinking that
>   they could thus make men suppose that what was said about Christ was a
>   mere tale of wonders like the stories told by the poets. [ . . . ]
>   But, as I will make clear, though they heard the words of the prophets
>   they did not understand them accurately, but **made mistakes in
>   imitating what was told about our Christ**. (First Apology 54)

The Trimurti also could be one of the ways Satan imitates God in order to make himself like God. Satan always wanted to become like God and that was the reason why Satan was cast out of Heaven (Isaiah 14:12-14).

Comment: This is a great answer except for Just as God is a Holy Trinity (Father, Son, Spirit), Satan also imitates God and creates the *Unholy Trinity (Satan, Antichrist, False Prophet)*. The words in italic being the problematic ones. I do not see the equating of Holy Spirit to false prophet. Any supporting material?

Comment: @FMShyanguya According to many Eschatologists, Revelation 12-13 gives us a picture of the Unholy Trinity which will appear at the end-times.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess it is something I haven't encountered in Catholic circles. It could be there but I am not familiar with it. But I guess if the *Holy Spirit has spoken through the prophets*, then what you have presented id not remote.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are entirely different. Whatever the new definitions being given by Wikipedians to Trimurti and Brahman, the original Vedas and Puranas has countless stories of bloody wars between the various gods/goddesses, and even wars between the devotees being supported by the different gods/goddesses.

Answer (score -1):

They are analogous though spoken in different languages and different theologies/philosophies. But there are also many differences, so it is best not to confuse them.

Trimurti, in classical Indian civilisation, is a tripartite way, of looking at the dynamism of the divine reality. In fact, this is close to Hegels conception of the original dynamic divine reality. And I wouldn't be surprised if this is where he got it from. He never acknowledged any of his sources, leaving us to suppose it was all his original work ...

Whereas the trinity, is a *hypostasis* of God, the Holy Spirit and Christ; but a single divine *ousia*, that is essence. It is three in one which is how it is understood to be a monotheism, despite its trinitarianism. Personally, I think this is from Christianity's Greek heritage, which notably is also a classical civilisation.

(I should say that personally, I'm a muslim).

Comment: The Trinity is three hypostases, not one hypostasis as this answer seems to say.