# Has the Mass ever been translated and said in Sanskrit?

Tags: catholicism, mass, translation

**Has the Mass ever been translated and said in Sanskrit?**

I remember reading some years ago about this possibility in Rome, by some Jesuit scholars, but can not find any sources to affirm that it has been done...

As we know, [Sanskrit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit) is the sacred language of Hinduism, the language of classical Hindu philosophy, and of historical texts of Buddhism and Jainism. [Sanskrit](https://www.mustgo.com/worldlanguages/sanskrit/) is also considered by many as the oldest language in the world.

I believe that this would be a great evangelizing tool in the countries such as India and Tibet (China).

Thus my question: **Has the Catholic Mass (in any Rite) ever been translated and said in Sanskrit?**

Answer (score 2):

It appears the answer is "Yes, but No".

[PrayTellBlog](https://www.praytellblog.com/index.php/2015/10/17/interculturation/) indicates that the Mass has been translated and used:

> “You are the fullness of Reality, One without a second. Being, Knowledge, Bliss. Om, tat, sat.” (*Om tat sat*, ओम् तत् सत्, is a Sanskrit mantra meaning these are “the three words of the three forms of god.”) In 1974, these words concluded the eucharistic prayer in the first “Order of Mass” published by the National Biblical, Catechetical, and Liturgical Centre in Bengaluru, India.

It is suppressed.

> Unfortunately, a 1975 letter from the cardinal prefect for the Congregation for Divine Worship “called a stop to [such] unauthorized experimentation,” and specifically cited the cessation of the Thomas Christians’ so-called “Indian Anaphora.” — *ibid.*

The very brief extract at the top of the quote might indicate the difficulty of rendering a monotheistic liturgy in the context of a language central to a polytheistic religion. It is all the more difficult to avoid falling into error when each religion contains similar (but certainly not identical) concepts: [Trinity (Christians) = Trimurti (Hindus)?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/18221/1377)